# How do I take a screenshot of a Text-Based User Interface?

Tags: unit-testing, terminal, screenshot, terminal-emulator

I have a program which is a Text-Based User Interface (TUI). Think ncurses. Everything is displayed in the terminal and a lot of ANSI escape sequences are used to display colors, scroll bars, windows, etc...

For unit testing, I want to take "screenshots" of the TUI and compare them to the expected screenshot. Essentially, the unit test needs to run a virtual terminal and save the output to a png image file.

Keep in mind, these tests need to run on a headless CI system like travis or circleci. I cannot simply run gnome-terminal and take a screenshot with gnome-screenshot. The CI system does not have graphics running.

How do I programmatically take a screenshot of a Text-Based User Interface on a "headless" system?

Comment: Use "screen" command, as described here: https://superuser.com/questions/557300/taking-a-screenshot-of-screen-session-over-ssh

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to take a screenshot using framebuffer, here is an example:
https://github.com/GunnarMonell/fbgrab

Comment: This looks promising. On LInux, /dev/fb contains the framebuffer in raw RGB bytes. It's a pretty simple algorithm to convert this to an image.